# Database Design: saving Google Maps data

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, database-design

SEE: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

I'm using MySQL.

Given a partial or complete address, the Google Map API will return something like this:

```
"address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
```

Assume I am developing an application wherein:

1. account owners can specify their location, and
2. search by location is supported

How should I store the address components I get from Google so that I can query for the following:

1. How many account owners in a particular country?
2. How many account owners in a particular state?
3. How many account owners in a particular ZIP/postal code?
4. etc.

One very easy way is to store individual address components in one table:

```
TABLE: account
- account_id (PK)
- street_number
- route
- locality
- administrative_area_level_2
- administrative_area_level_1
- country
- postal_code
```

I'll just leave blank whatever information Google does not provide (e.g. if account owner did not provide a street number, then the Google API also won't return the `street_number`). I think this would be the simplest to query. However, this data won't be normalized.

Alternatively, I could could design the database to have multiple tables, for example:

```
TABLE: country
- country_id (PK)
- name

TABLE: administrative_area_level_1
- administrative_area_level_1_id (PK)
- country_id (FK)
- name
```

... and so on

This will probably normalize the data, but might be a pain to query. Also, missing information might also cause some problems. For example, what if Google returns `country` and `administrative_area_level_2`, skipping `administrative_area_level_1` (I'm not sure if this is even possible)?  `administrative_area_level_2` would require a `administrative_area_level_1_id` as its FK -- and without it, the model breaks.

Another idea might be to use a nested set or adjacency model. The data would be normalized and would probably be able to deal better with missing information.

My gut feeling is that the simplest model -- the one allowing redundant data -- is the best option for me. The data is not coming from me, it's coming from Google and I *think* I only need the data so I can do these search-by-location searches. Maybe I won't run into anomalies?

**Any suggestions on how to model this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start worrying about how to model the data you retrieve from Google Maps, you might want to check out the terms of service first, at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html.
Particularly take note of 10.1.3 (a):

*"You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof..."*

I'd say that pretty much explicitly prohibits the kind of application you're trying to build. If you want to query the address information Google has about one of your account owners, you have to do it using Google's APIs - not copying their data and doing it in your own application.

Comment: Alastair, please disregard the issue of the TOS (and potentially violating it) and try to address the data modeling question. The same general problem would occur using a different mapping service. Plus, it seems that it's OK to store Google Map data in some cases: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html#caching

Comment: If you'd asked this as a data modelling question in an abstract sense, that would have been fine, but given that you've said that you want the answer specifically in order to develop an application that breaks the law, I'm certainly not going to help you further. Caching is a very specific use case that is only allowed for "limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service" (10.1.3b of ToS) - that does not cover your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your time. By the way, Google's TOS is not law. And my question still stands as a DB modeling question.

Comment: Usage of the Google APIs is subject to acceptance of a legal agreement, and you're asking for help in doing something that contravenes the terms of that legal agreement. Again, this is all set out in the terms of use - I strongly encourage you to read them.